# Adding a IEEE-754 Floating Point and a Float number in C++

Tags: c++, ieee-754

I have two variables.

**variable_1** = **01000001000011110101110000101001**(0x410f5c29 in IEEE-754 Floating Point format) which is 8.96 in Decimal.

```
float variable_2 = 0.2
```

I want to add them like

```
float variable_3 = variable_1 + variable_2; // in C++
```

I just need to know how will I assign them to variables so that they are taken what they are. This will include declaring variable_1 and assiging it the value.

Comment: Put those bits into a 32-bit unsigned int. memcpy from the int to a float.

Comment: See [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule/51228315#51228315) In particular the section "What is Type Punning" and following

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an unsigned integer to the desired bits and use `std::memcpy` to copy them into a `float`:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>


int main()
{
    uint32_t au = 0x410f5c29;
    float    a;

    static_assert(sizeof (float) == sizeof (uint32_t),
        "sizes of float and uint32_t must be the same");
    std::memcpy(&a, &au, sizeof a);

    float    b  = .2;
    float    c  = a+b;

    std::cout << std::setprecision(99);
    std::cout << "a = " << a << ".\n";
    std::cout << "b = " << b << ".\n";
    std::cout << "c = " << c << ".\n";
}
```

Sample output:

```
a = 8.96000003814697265625.
b = 0.20000000298023223876953125.
c = 9.159999847412109375.
```

Comment: Any particular preference for `std::memcpy` instead of a `union`? E.g. `union { float f; uint32_t u; } fu; fu.u = 0x410f5c29; float a = fu.f;`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: The question is tagged C++. The C standard defines reading a union member other than the last one written to reinterpret its bits. The C++ standard does not define it. Compilers will optimize a short constant `std::memcpy` like this one.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you!